# Is there a way to specify base url for the browser to fetch on the same origin?

Tags: http, web, https, http-headers

I want to proxy `foo.com/some/path/<somepath>` to `bar.com/<somepath>` on my web application.
So when the user enters `foo.com/some/path/example.html` he will get the content my backend fetches from `bar.com/example.html`. But when the browser renders the HTML on `foo.com/some/path/example.html` - for example we have a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">`, I want it to fetch `bar.com/some/path/main.css` but as it is - the browser fetches `bar.com/main.css`.
Important note: I can't edit the content on `bar.com/<somepath>`.
How can I change the base url it fetches from? (On the same origin)

Comment: Can you change your proxy to rewrite URLs on the fly?

Comment: What you describe is actually a "reverse proxy."  Which tool are you using to implement it?  It will depend on the functionality of your reverse proxy software.  Apache can do it, look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431090/proxyhtml-to-rewrite-url

Comment: I build my own proxy in NodeJS using `node-fetch`, I can do anything on the fly. What can I do?